# SQL WHERE clause logic mismatch

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with the following information

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | status | action | reason |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | CN     | WAPP   | BDEC   |
|  2 | CN     | DENY   | PREF   |
|  3 | AP     | APPL   | MI     |
|  4 | AP     | MATR   | AUTO   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

A MySQL query to select data from this table has been written with a specific filter to exclude all records matching CN-WAPP-BDEC.

```
SELECT *
FROM   `table`
WHERE  (`status` != 'CN' AND `action` != 'WAPP' AND `reason` != 'BDEC');
```

However, it only returns records 3 and 4, record #2 is also excluded.

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `table`
WHERE  CONCAT(`status`, `action`, `reason`) != 'CNWAPPBDEC';
```

Only then, do I get the expected result: records 2, 3, and 4.

As far as I can tell, the queries should both do the exact same thing, but they obviously aren't, and I'm confused as to why that is. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record 2 is excluded because status = CN, which makes the first condition `status != 'CN'` false.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `table`
WHERE  (NOT (`status` == 'CN' AND `action` == 'WAPP' AND `reason` == 'BDEC'));
```

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the use of parentheses should be grouping all of the logic together such that all three conditions would need to be met, not just one?

Comment: That's how it is written.  I took the liberty of wrapping the whole condition in parens, just in case that is a specific requirement of MySQL.

Comment: It's how it is written in my original as well. I guess I'm getting stuck on why the grouping of AND's isn't excluding only record 1. If record 2 only matches 1 criteria out of 3, but all 3 criteria are grouped, why is record 2 not being matched against all 3, and thereby since it's not fulfilling all 3, included? Am I making sense?

Comment: You're reading `AND` the wrong way.  `AND` means "It must fulfill *all* of my stated conditions."  Record 2 does not meet all of your stated conditions, which is why it is being excluded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `OR`, not `AND`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM  `table` t
WHERE `status` <> 'CN' OR `action` <> 'WAPP' OR `reason` <> 'BDEC';
```

You can also phrase this using tuples:

```
WHERE (status, action, reason) not in ( ('CN', 'WAPP', 'BDEC') );
```